# SendGrid some images not showing up in HTML mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tinymce, sendgrid

Im using Sendgrid with Ruby on rails version 2.3.18 and tinymce editor to send campaign emails through my app.

When i try to send a campaign HTML email with **multiple** linked images inside it (stored on amazon), some of the images gets broken and not displayed.
when checking the email in developer tools, i see that the broken images SRC is messed up.
The weird thing is:
1. It happens even if i send an email with the **same image** multiple times.
2. I debugged my code to the last line of code before SendGrid takes over, and all of the images SRC are identical and works properly up to that point.

Here is the content of the campaign email before Sendgrid takes over, notice that the 7th img tag is identical to all of the other img tags:

http://pastebin.com/UxTUxxLY

and this is what renders in the email itself (dev tools on the mail),
Notice how the 7th img tag SRC attribute is different than the rest, even though its the same image:

http://pastebin.com/EWB4a0tR

Iv tried different email supplier such as hotmail to see wheter its an issue with gmail specificly, and its not.

any idea what could be the source of the image breaking?

Comment: Post your production environment config please

Comment: there you go: http://pastie.org/10946602